# How to extract expression from ConditionalExpression

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, expression-manipulation

```
p1 := y /. {First[Solve[x^2 + y^2 + x == 1, y, Reals]]}
```

> ```
> {ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[1 - x - x^2], 
>    1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) < x < 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])]}
> ```

I want to get the `-Sqrt[1 - x - x^2]` out of the conditional expression and assign it to a variable. I don't care about the conditions, I'm aware of them and need the expression for use out of the `ConditionalExpression`. How do I do that?

I tried list commands combinations (`Flatten`, `First`, etc.) but they don't work with this. Am I just supposed to copy-paste?

Comment: Have you tried `Part`? Like in `%[[1,1]]`. (By the way, with `:=` you should not get any output, perhaps you meant `p1=...`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `Normal`, `ConditionalExpression` is not explicitly mentioned there but documentation says it deals with special forms.

```
p1 = y /. {First[Solve[x^2 + y^2 + x == 1, y, Reals]]} // First
```

> ```
>  ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[1 - x - x^2], 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) < x < 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])]
> ```

```
Normal @ p1
```

> ```
> -Sqrt[1 - x - x^2]
> ```

Comment: Ah didn't know `Normal` can handle this! +1!

Answer (score 7):

You can forcely specify the condition to be `True`:

```
Solve[x^2 + y^2 + x == 1, y, Reals] /.
 ConditionalExpression[e_, _] :> ConditionalExpression[e, True]
```

> ```
> {{y -> -Sqrt[1 - x - x^2]}, {y -> Sqrt[1 - x - x^2]}}
> ```

But you should always keep it in mind that this is not an identical transformation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Simplify[ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[1 - x - x^2], 
  1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) < x < 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])],
 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) < x < 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])]

 (*    -Sqrt[1 - x - x^2]       *)
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is to use `Simplify` or `Fullsimplify`

```
Simplify @@ 
 ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[1 - x - x^2], 
  1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[5]) < x < 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])]
```

returns

```
-Sqrt[1 - x - x^2]
```