# How do I get exact results from Solve?

Tags: equation-solving

When I evaluate

```
Solve[Log[-0.5 + 10^x + Sin[x]]/Log[10] == x, x]
```

I get the output

> ```
> {{x -> ConditionalExpression[0.523599 + 6.28319 C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}, 
>  {x -> ConditionalExpression[2.61799 + 6.28319 C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}}
> ```

How can I results in the form:

```
x -> π/6 + 2 π C[1]
x -> 5 π/6 + 2 π C[1]
```

Comment: The input should have only exact numbers.  Anything with a decimal point is *not* exact. Change `0.5` to `1/2`, for more difficult cases use `Rationalize` with a threshold of 0.

Comment: This is discussed here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html

Comment: So once you have `-1/2` you can just use `Normal @ Solve[...`, see: [How to extract expression from ConditionalExpression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38579/5478)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Szabolcs has already explained why you should replace .5 with 1/2. Perhaps you also want remove the `ConditionalExpression` wrapper. Then

```
Solve[Log[-1/2 + 10^x + Sin[x]]/Log[10] == x, x] /. 
  ConditionalExpression[arg_, ___] -> arg
```

> `{{x -> π/6 + 2 π C[1]}, {x -> (5 π)/6 + 2 π C[1]}}`

is what you are looking for.